# How can I write this statement from infix to postfix?

Tags: compiler-construction

How can I write this statement:

```
9-3/(1+2)
```

... from infix to postfix?

Comment: You might want to ask this type of question on mathoverflow.com also.

Answer (score 5):

9-3/(1+2)

First would be (1+2) since it has the highest order of operation.

```
-> 1 2 +
```

Then 3 divided by the result...

```
-> 3 1 2 + /
```

Then 9 minus the result....

```
-> 9 3 1 2 + / -
```

Answer (score 3):

9 3 1 2 + / - (and more stuff to make 15 characters)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Shunting-yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting_yard_algorithm) to convert from infix to postfix notation.